# Setting up TortoiseHg on a server

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, windows-server

I would like to setup tortoisehg on my server. I did it.

I have setup  webserver that  tortoisehg provide. But I would like to manage users that can use repositories (can read/write) how I can setup users with their password?

I very like this functionality like VisualSVN server does http://www.visualsvn.com/server/. Is  it possible to have something similar with tortoisehg?

Comment: TortoiseHG is a frontend GUI for Mercurial - what did you "setup" on your server?  What O/S is the server?

Comment: I just install TortoiseHG. And with TortoiseHG webserver i see repositories. But I would like to make it more secure add users etc. Windows 2008. this server in a cloud.

Comment: You need to forget about TortoiseHG etc, and use a proper webserver which will allow you to configure access control.  The webserver supplied with TortoiseHG is just a Python implementation and isn't designed to be that reliable.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, do you know names for this webservers for Windows but for mercurial  ?

Comment: I use Linux, but I know there is IIS and Apache that work under Windows.  You really need one that can support normal Mercurial hgweb.cgi and forget about Tortoise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was doing it on a Windows Server 2000, I didn't want to mess with Apache, and ended up using this HOWTO for setting up hg serve behind nginx:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgServeNginx

The trick here is that you need to run hg serve as a Windows Service. You'll need [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) or something like it for doing that.

This only allows a config where everyone can read, but only authenticated users can push, or, if you remove `limit_except GET`, where only authenticated users can read and push. More detailed permission schemes require additional setup.